# How to add decimals to php function output

Tags: php, wordpress, numbers, format, decimal

I have custom function that sums up values from custom fields in the wordpress database.

The values are summed up correctly and presented like this: 
1500.3€

How can I add a trailing zero to the decimal so the sum would be presented like this
1500.30€

I'm thinking I need to format the $sum with number_format() but I'm not a 100% sure how to use number_format with my function.

It should look something like this:

```
number_format($sum, 2, '.', '');
```

But can I just stick the above to my function?

The custom function:

```
function kd_shortcode_group_progress($atts, $content = null) {
 extract( shortcode_atts( array(
    'challenge' => '0',
    'group' => '1',
), $atts ) );

global $wpdb;
$prefix = $wpdb->prefix;
global $kd_table;
$table = $prefix."postmeta";
$table2 = $prefix."posts";

$sum = 0;

$sql = "SELECT `post_id` FROM `".$table."` WHERE `meta_key` = 'wpcf-haaste_valmis' and `meta_value` = '".$challenge."';";
$people = $wpdb->get_results($sql);

$sql4 = "SELECT `id` as `post_id` FROM `".$table2."` WHERE `post_type` = 'osallistuja' and `post_title` = '".$group."';";
$ids = $wpdb->get_results($sql4);

$pageId = '';
foreach ($ids as $i => $id) {
    $people[] = $ids[$i];
}

foreach ($people as $i => $val) {
    $pid = $val->post_id;

    $sql2 = "SELECT `meta_value` as 'value' FROM `".$table."` WHERE `meta_key` = 'wpcf-keratty' AND `post_id` = '".$pid."';";
    $sql3 = "SELECT SUM(`price`) as 'value' FROM `".$kd_table."` WHERE `for` = '".$pid."';";

    $dons1 = $wpdb->get_results($sql2);
    $dons2 = $wpdb->get_results($sql3);

    foreach ($dons1 as $i2 => $val2) {
        $sum += $val2->value;
    }
    foreach ($dons2 as $i2 => $val3) {
        $sum += $val3->value;
    }   
}

return '<div class="groupDonations"><span style="color:#55A228!important;">This group has collected </span><br>'.$sum.'€</span></div>';
}
```

Comment: Yes. Exactly that. Did you get an unexpected result when you tried it?

Comment: Hi! I did try this:
     $sum = 0;
     number_format($sum, 2, '.', '');

But it didn't do anything.

Comment: I didn't realise I had to put it like this:
     $sum = 0; 

     $sum = number_format($sum, 2, '.', '')

Now it's working.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use WordPress [number_format_i18n](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/number_format_i18n/)

```
$formatted = number_format_i18n( 1500.3, 2 ); // 1500.30
```

`number_format` also works but it is language independent

```
echo number_format(1500.3, 2, '.', ''); // 1500.30
```

[Try it online here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/5124d08ff33d732c0d3698d774dabea99316fc0e)

Comment: Hi! 
I tried both methods and both worked. I'm using the number_format_i18n now.
I wasn't aware that wordpress had a locale based number formatting function before.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
$sum = 0; 
echo number_format($sum, 2, '.', '');
```

works fine - could be a front-end problem with actually showing it?
try using it as a string,

```
$sum = "" . number_format($sum, 2, '.', '');
```